# Not able to connect to linux server using winscp because of login script

Tags: server, bash, scripts, ssh, scp

I am not able to connect to my remote hosting server using Winscp. I have set the file protocol as SFTP and shell as bin/bash. I am getting the following error after entering the username and password:

> Received too large (1164866661 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet
>   size is 1024000B.
>
> The error is typically caused by message printed from startup script
>   (like .profile). The message may start with "Ente".

When I log in to the remote server manually, the following script is printed

> Entering CT 
>   entered into CT 30123

So I think this is the script due which winscp is not able to connect.

However I am not able to find where this script printing logic is written in order for me to alter that.

Can anyone help me in finding and altering the script or may be finding a better resolution

Comment: Have you added stuff ahead of the interactivity check (`case $- in ... esac`) in your `.bashrc` file?